# How to mantain JPA @Transient field after saved to DB

Tags: java, jpa

I have a @Transient field in an entity, example :

```
@Transient
private String tempName;
```

In my method I'm setting a random string into this **tempName**, but the value in **tempName** is lost after saved to DB.

This field is not a column in the tables, so I make it **@Transient**, but I need to get back the value assign to **tempName** for the following process.

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: So, you're essentially asking: 'how do I make persistent a property that I explicitly marked to not be persistent'. I'm not sure what sort of answers you're hoping to get

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways such as caching, threadlocal etc.. At the end of the day, if you need that value just add a column and save it to the database.